# Create many sprite notes at the same time

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, skspritenode, swift5

I program a space shooter in Swift. If you have killed the last alien, more aliens should come. I tried it that way:

```
for _ in 1...level {

    let alien: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "alien")

    alien.setScale(0.05)
    alien.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width))), y: size.height + alien.size.height)
    alien.zPosition = 0
    alien.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "alien"), size: alien.size)
    alien.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
    alien.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    alien.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2

    addChild(alien)

    // Move 'alien'.
    alien.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: alien.position.x, y: CGFloat((arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.height / 2) + 1) + UInt32(size.height / 2)))), duration: 3))

    aliens += 1

}
```

---

If I've killed the last alien, the expected aliens are coming, but the FPS number goes from 60.0 to 50.0.

**Is it possible to generate multiple sprites at the same time without reducing the FPS count?**

**Or is there a solution to add the sprites one at a time, as with a timer?**

---

Usually it looks like this:

[Klick to show picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgq0l.png)

Comment: How long does the framerate remain at 50 fps?  What does the node count do?

Comment: About 30 nodes are displayed and the FPS number stays at 50.0 for 3 seconds.

Comment: It could be you are adding too many nodes in a single frame.  One way to solve that is to add one (or a few) nodes per frame.  Another way is to have a pool of nodes that exist but are not all added to the scene; i.e. you never create and destroy alien nodes during gameplay.  However if you are adding only a few dozen nodes I would not expect the framerate to drop so drastically.

Comment: Also if you are developing using the iOS Simulator you won't get Metal hardware support until macOS 10.15 and iOS 13.  I would recommend creating both a macOS and iOS target in your project and developing using macOS so you get Metal hardware support.  Test regularly on iOS and don't use the Simulator at all.

Comment: I always add only 1 to 9 sprites.

Comment: Are you developing using the Simulator?  If so, either do as I mention above or stop worrying about performance.

Comment: I'm running the app for testing on my Mac. (Without the Simulator)

Comment: So it's a macOS app?  That framerate is a very bad sign then.

Comment: Is there a solution to add the sprites one at a time like a timer?

Comment: It's pretty simple.  Keep a count of how many aliens currently exist and how many aliens you ideally want to exist.  If the first value is less than the second value then simply add one alien in that frame.

Comment: The problem is, I only want to add new aliens when all the other aliens are gone. And the aliens are to be inserted by a single function.

Comment: You need to have a think about the problem.  When aliens die you reduce `alienAliveCount`.  When you add an alien you increase `alienAliveCount`.  When processing a frame `if alienAliveCount < alienTargetCount { addAlien() }`.  It's a very simple problem and you will face much greater challenges while developing a game.

Comment: OK. I will try it that way.

Comment: It works out! I've created a kill ad instead of a level ad and now there's only one new alien after every kill. The FPS number is almost no longer decreasing. **Thank you!**